# In xcode 6.1, interface builder deleting ui elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a view with some tableviews and some collection views and also some buttons and labels.

I'm not sure if this is new with Xcode 6.1 because I have not worked on the ui aspect of this project for some time.  However, when I try to resize just about anything in the view, my tableviews and collection views, and possibly some other elements I am not noticing, get deleted.  Specifically, it seems their frame or rect propertied get deleted.

To be clear, this only occurs when I attempt to resize the element by dragging the sides in interface builder.  If I resize them by changing the numbers directly either in the IB sidebar or in the xml, this does not happen.

I'm wondering if this is a bug in Xcode or if I have done something to cause this behavior which I can change.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. It's a lot of fun constantly resizing and moving views back into place after XCode sets their frames to 0,0,0,0.

Comment: This is definitely a very disturbing bug affecting autolayout in Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Confirmed that it's working fine in Xcode 6.3 beta. I am not sure why but my live Xcode won't "App Store" update to 6.1.1 so it's stuck with the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I acheived a fix, at least for this project by turning off auto layout in "show the file inspector" -> "interface builder document"

I have never used this feature in the past so I do not know if it was on in the past but I am wondering if the new Xcode version turns it on by default where the others left it off.
It may also be possible that it has always been on but there is a bug in the feature in the new version.

This fixed the issue for me, at least in this particular project and at least for now.  I hope others find this useful.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a fix since auto layout is important for many apps in iOS8.

Answer (score 2):

From here it looks like a bug in Xcode 6.1.

I created a clean project and the behaviour is the same on my machine:

https://github.com/nasht/Xcode6ConstraintTest.git

Resizing one view makes others disappear. Changing a layout constraint from a = to <= or >= also seems to do it.

I've raised a bug with Apple. Suggest you do the same.

**workaround:** You can install xcode 6.01 and use interface builder from there. You can still compile and run your code using xcode 6.1 if you're relying on xcode 6.1 specific features. (you'll need to rename your xcode.app so you can run both instances. ) It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Solved with XCode 6.1.1 for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that it's fixed on the next version of xcode (6.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

same problem, yosemit and xocde 6.1. I can resize some view only if i disable autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into this 'problem'. I believe this was because one of the constraints I had was not setup correctly.

Comment: do yo remember any specifics?

Comment: @Mason Make sure all of your views have constraints relative to other views and a top and bottom constraint to the container view (parent view).

Answer (score 0):

What OS X Version are you on? I updated to Yosemite today and 6.1 along with it. When I would resize a label my other elements were not getting deleted but instead getting resized and repositioned. The width / height would change to 0,0 and the x / y would change to 0,0 as well.

I was noticing other issues with Yosemite so went ahead and did a time capsule restore back to Mavericks and Xcode 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in universal app; iphone works fine and the ipad doesnt work.

I'm using xCode 6.1 and OSX Yosemite
My app supports iOS7 and iOS8 and i had the same problem on iOS7 on iPad version only

Fix:

> So i fixed it by setting **Simulated Metrics** in interface builder by
>   **Size = iPad Full Screen** and **Orientation by Landscape or Portrait**

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same kind of problem with Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite :
I have created a view that I have added to the main view, so it appears like a sub view in the View Controller Scene.
Then I resize this subview to 320 x 568. My program works. It corresponds to the program dropit of Stanford CS193P Lecture 9.
I save the project, close it and reopen it : the subview has its width and height set to 0 !

I tried to open the project dropit of Lecture 8 that is quite the same, which was working before (I think in Xcode 6) and same problem ! First I thought that tapping (related to the subview) was not working but found out that tapping was not working because I was tapping on a subview which has its width and height set to 0 !

Answer (score 0):

I have reset the size class wCompact hAny to which all the UIElements are added. and got corrected.