# In Xcode 6, why is the Image View keep automatically resizing when I try to resize a subview within it?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Posted is a picture of my issue.

[image]

I'm fairly new to Xcode and I have a UIImageView object in my View. I added another View (white rectangular box) within the View, and below the UIImageView object.

If I try to resize the inner View in any way using the cursor, the Image View resizes to 0 as shown below. However if I use the Size Inspector (ruler icon) on the right to resize the subview, the Image View stays the same size. What the heck?

[image]

Is there some setting I need to adjust? Thanks

Comment: xcode 6.1 issue

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537135/in-xcode-6-1-interface-builder-deleting-ui-elements/26606452#26606452][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537135/in-xcode-6-1-interface-builder-deleting-ui-elements/26606452#26606452