# Resize Issue in XCODE 6.1 - resize of one element sets width, height, X, and Y of another to 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

(iOS 8, Xcode 6.1, Objective-C, iPhone/iPad)

I'm experiencing some weird behavior Xcode. Anyone else see this?

Steps to reproduce:
1. Drag two webviews into the same view
2. Resize one of the view by grabbing one of the little handles on the corners.
3. Other webview's width and height, and X and Y coords are set to 0 for the other webview?!

In Figure 1 below, I have two webviews. I have selected one, grabbed it by a handle to resize.

After releasing the mouse button, the *second* webview's coordinates and dimensions have all been set to 0.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm totally with you, having that all the time ... Hopefully there will be new version soon with this bug fixed ...

Comment: As far as I remember that only happens if you haven't set any (or enough) constraints.

Answer (score 0):

i'm hoping that you are using AutoLayout in your xib or storyboard. You can fix this by disabling AutoLayout in your xib/storyboard. **BUT** if you want to use Autolayout in your views then you should set constraints in your UI elements.

In your case you should set constraints in Webview on the right side then drag and drop or resize the web view on the left side.

I'm guessing that Xcode is getting confused and setting them to (0,0,0,0) by checking their constraints.

This is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537135/in-xcode-6-1-interface-builder-deleting-ui-elements)